# Uninstalling package unrecognized by aptitude

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, troubleshooting, aptitude

Some times ago I installed qtikz on my system, but I don't remember if I did it via dpkg -i --force-architecture or directly from source (perhaps via checkinstall). In short, it is not working and I want to replace it with the qtikz 64 bit version of ubuntu precise (I am using ubuntu natty). So I downloaded the package and did:

```
sudo gdebi qtikz_0.10-1_amd64.deb
```

Which gives the error message:

```
dpkg: error processing qtikz_0.10-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 qtikz: 0.10-1 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with qtikz:i386 0.10-1 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qtikz_0.10-1_amd64.deb
```

Then I tried to purge the old qtikz via aptitude: `sudo aptitude purge qtikz`, which gives me: `No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.` Similar result with `dpkg -r qtikz`.

`aptitude search qtikz` gives no results.

and via `apt-get` I get:

```
sudo apt-get purge qtikz
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'qtikz' can't be removed
```

`locate qtikz` results in

```
/usr/bin/qtikz
/usr/lib/mime/packages/qtikz
/usr/share/qtikz
/usr/share/applications/qtikz.desktop
/usr/share/doc/qtikz
/usr/share/doc/qtikz/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/qtikz/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/qtikz/copyright
/usr/share/kde4/apps/ktikz/locale/qtikz_de.qm
/usr/share/kde4/apps/ktikz/locale/qtikz_es.qm
/usr/share/kde4/apps/ktikz/locale/qtikz_fr.qm
/usr/share/man/man1/qtikz.1.gz
/usr/share/menu/qtikz
/usr/share/mime/packages/qtikz.xml
/usr/share/pixmaps/qtikz16.xpm
/usr/share/pixmaps/qtikz32.xpm
/usr/share/qtikz/documentation
/usr/share/qtikz/locale
/usr/share/qtikz/qtikz-128.png
/usr/share/qtikz/templates
/usr/share/qtikz/documentation/qtikz.qch
/usr/share/qtikz/documentation/qtikz.qhc
/usr/share/qtikz/locale/qtikz_de.qm
/usr/share/qtikz/locale/qtikz_es.qm
/usr/share/qtikz/locale/qtikz_fr.qm
/usr/share/qtikz/templates/beamer-example-template.pgs
/usr/share/qtikz/templates/template_example.pgs
/usr/share/qtikz/templates/template_example2.pgs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qtikz.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qtikz.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qtikz.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qtikz.postrm
```

So any ideas, how to savely remove this package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the architecture when you remove i386 package. I.e. remove it by executing `sudo dpkg -r qtikz:i386`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using dpkg directly:

```
dpkg -P qtikz
```

Did it work?